# Why are there more threads in one execution than in the other?

Tags: python, multithreading

I have a scenario I'm trying to wrap my head arround.

So I have two different servers I need to connect to, each having a different response time (one is fast, one is slow). There's a for loop which runs for a fixed amount of time for both servers, creating threads and starting them. Basically I'm making multiple asynchronous requests to these servers, storing their reply time in a list.

Here's the code:

```
 while time.time() - start_time < run_time:

    thread = Thread(target=thread_method, args=())
    thread.start()
    thread_list.append(thread)

# make sure all threads finish before continuing
 for thread in thread_list:
    thread.join()
```

and each thread has something like this:

```
start_time = time.time()
call_the_server()
end_time = time.time()

latency_list.append(start_time-end_time))
```

Executing the same script for each server, with the same run_time, give me let's say X items, while the second one X*3.

My thought is that creating the thread, starting it and then moving to the next one in the loop might result in the same number of items in both cases, the only difference being that one script run might finish a little later, as each thread might end later (due to the higher response time of the server).

I could really use an explanation for why i'm getting these results.

Comment: Say thanks to GIL. One thread works faster then Multi Threading in Python. The only benefit of using Threads in Python is asynchronous behavior. You must use Processes in Python to enjoy from parallel code execution.

Comment: Can you tell the reasoning behind your code?

Comment: @AlexanderRavikovich really? Do you have any links to materials I could read up on this.  I'm not a python developer, however this question did interest me.

Comment: https://42bits.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/python-global-interpreter-lock-gil-explained-pycon-tech-talk/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered by Alexander Ravikovich in a comment.

https://42bits.wordpress.com/2010/10/24/python-global-interpreter-lock-gil-explained-pycon-tech-talk/

or

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Obt-vMVdM8s